# What's a good approach to handle time interval in mysql that starts in one day and ends in another?

Tags: mysql

For example, if you wanted to make a SELECT statement to query values that were added from 6pm yesterday until 10 am today, what functions would be involved?

Some background:

I'm making an app where people rate nightclubs live, so the timespan of one night out is usually from 6pm one day until 10 pm the next. To make even more clear imagine you are going out and want to know if 'X' club or venue it's good today. The app i'm making registers votes of the size of the line of the club, if people should get in or not,etc.. So, if one person votes that you should get it (at 0:46 am) and other says the line it's very big at 22pm, both informations should appear. You only want to know the votes 'X' club received between 6pm till 10 am of the next day. You don't want to know how the club went 'yesterday' or last week. You want to know how the place is going today. I'm sorry if I was being confusing,I think now it's more clear.

So, how do you handle intervals that start one day and end another?

P.S. I'm starting to think that using

```
WHERE DATE(date_added) = CURDATE()
```

and its variants are not a good approach, since the next day will mess up with the logic involved. (my date column is date_added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date_added is a timestamp or a datetime, I assume.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE date_added BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d 22:00:00') 
                     AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d 10:00:00')
```

EDIT:

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE date_added BETWEEN CASE WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '23:59:59' THEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d 22:00:00') 
                              WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '10:00:00' THEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d 22:00:00') 
                         ELSE NULL
                         END
                 AND     CASE WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '23:59:59' THEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d 10:00:00')
                              WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '10:00:00' THEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d 10:00:00')
                         ELSE NULL
                         END
```

The result is NULL when the query is not fired within the time range.

Comment: That was very clever @tombom and i myself fell in this error. Which is in this case we are presuming that mysql could 'preview' what would be the next day values. Like if today is 06-28 at 11pm, the values from 06-29 are not yet available, because they are in the future. And if today is 06-29 at 0:30 am the values posted the day before till 10pm wouldn't show up. This by no means it's a harsh critic, i'm just trying to explain the situation, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. When your DB has no values in it, what are you trying to query then? Please include a detailed list in your question, which data you expect at which point of query execution time.

Comment: Imagine you are going out and want to know if 'X' club or venue it's good today. The app i'm making registers votes of the size of the line of the club, if people should get in or not,etc.. So, if one person votes that you should get it (at 0:46 am) and other says the line it's very big at 22pm, both informations should appear.  You only want to know the votes 'X' club received between 6pm till 10 am of the next day. You don't want to know how the club went 'yesterday' or last week. You want to know how the place is going today. I'm sorry if I was being confusing,I think now it's more clear.

Comment: What if the query is fired at 5pm? Should the result be empty then?

Comment: Now you've got it! Yes there is a gap between 10am and 6pm(10:00 to 18:00 hrs)  because the app targets night events. I will try to figure out how to handle the evening events in the future. But for now this time span of 6pm till 10am is a good mark.  (18:00 of present day to 10:00 hrs of the next day)

Comment: Okay, glad to hear I could help. Feel free to accept the answer and/or upvote it :)

Comment: Man i was dying to give you the accept / upvote and donate all my points to you as soon as I saw your edit, because your answer was freaking brilliant. But after a few tries it didn't turn out as we expected. I've tried all sort of fixes but finally i have come to a final solution. The credit goes all to you, but if you could edit your answer with the code provided in the comment bellow i think people that may struggle with this situation too could benefit. Thanks!! :)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE  ( (CASE WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '23:59:59' THEN ((DATE(date_added) = CURDATE() )AND HOUR(date_added)>17)   
                         ELSE NULL
                         END )   OR  ( CASE  WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '09:59:59' THEN (((DATE(date_added) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND HOUR(date_added)>17 ) OR  ((DATE(date_added) = CURDATE() ) AND HOUR(date_added)<11 ))                         ELSE NULL
                         END)   
      )`

Comment: What this does is that if the current time is between 18:00 and 23:59, it will find the current date values with hour bigger than 17. Or if the time is between 00:00 and 9:59 it will find the values from yesterday with hour bigger than 17 or from today with hour less than 11.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BETWEEN` query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE date_added BETWEEN '2013-06-27 18:00:00' and '2013-06-28 22:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your time @Klaus, but this is for a specific date. And if you look at my comment at tombom answer you will see that the generalization of this approach would also lead into a incorrect solution. I really appreciate your help and it'svery close of what it's needed, but it's missing some details. I'm sorry if i wasn't clear enough from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `StartTime` and `EndTime` column, if you care about the times.  To find what is happening now:

```
where now() between StartTime and EndTime
```

If you want to know what is happening on a particular date:

```
where @THEDATE between date(StartTime) and date(EndTime)
```

A word of caution about `between` for date/times.  It works as expected when you are comparing times and times (the first example) or dates and dates (the second example).  It may not do what you want when comparing times and dates (not shown).

Comment: This isn't helpful, or even correct, unless you add the requirement that `StartTime` and `EndTime` must be datetime data type columns, not time.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Gordon, but that's not what is being asked. Take a look at the other two answers and you will see what is the demand of the question.